# sftp backups with duplicity fail

Tags: sftp, debian-wheezy, duplicity

I'm using duplicity on debian wheezy, which comes with version 0.6.18 as standard package. I also tried version 0.6.24 from wheezy-backports.

I want to use sftp as backend, but if I run:

```
duplicity --full-if-older-than 1M --exclude /run --exclude /proc --exclude /lost+found --exclude /dev --exclude /sys --exclude /mnt / sftp://$FTP_USER"@"$FTP_HOSTNAME/myserver
```

I get the following error:

```
ssh: Exception: Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm)
ssh: Traceback (most recent call last):
ssh:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1546, in run
ssh:     self._handler_table[ptype](self, m)
ssh:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1618, in _negotiate_keys
ssh:     self._parse_kex_init(m)
ssh:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1731, in _parse_kex_init
ssh:     raise SSHException('Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm)')
ssh: SSHException: Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm)
ssh:
```

I've read that this is might related to the paramiko backend which is used as default, but when I change it to pexpect (...pexpect+sftp://...) I get this error:

```
UnsupportedBackendScheme: scheme not supported in url: pexpect+sftp://
```

How can that issue be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the command

```
duplicity /source-dir pexpect+sftp://backup.server.com/storage
```

to

```
duplicity /source-dir --ssh-backend=pexpect sftp://backup.server.com/storage
```

Tested with duplicity 0.6.24 on debian jessie 8.7

man duplicity:

> --ssh-backend backend
>
> Allows the explicit selection of a ssh backend. 
>    Defaults to paramiko.
>
> Alternatively you might choose pexpect.

The scheme 'pexpect+sftp://' was introduced in a later version of duplicity.